# How reverse attributes object of type OpenStruct ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following object of type Interactor::Context. This is OpenStruct.

```
#<Interactor::Context id=1, object_id=2, test_exception_id=3, secret_field=#<String>, valid_model=#<String>, extra_field=#<String>>
```

I need to reverse this object.

I tried with following code:

```
h = before_reverse_obj.marshal_dump.to_a.reverse.to_h
obj_reverse = JSON.parse(h.to_json, object_class: Interactor::Context)
```

Returns just hash object:

```
{"extra_field"=>"#<String>",
 "valid_model"=>"#<DataTables::DataAnalytic id=1004>",
 "secret_field"=>"#<String>",
 "test_exception_id"=>3,
 "object_id"=>2,
 "id"=>1}
```

But need return object Interaction::Context.

How correct reverse?

Answer (score 0):

`Interaction::Context` isn't an OpenStruct, it is a [`Interaction::Context` that inherits from `OpenStruct`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor/blob/master/lib/interactor/context.rb#L31), but has more methods that an simple `OpenStruct`.

That means what you want is the class of that object:

```
before_reverse_obj.class
#=> Interactor::Context
```

or the class name (string) of that object:

```
before_reverse_obj.class.name
#=> "Interactor::Context"
```